# Deploying Flask App (Which uses a SQLAlchemy Database and APScheduler) to Google Cloud App Engine with connection with Google Cloud API

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, apscheduler

I am new to coding and this is the first time i've tried to deploy an App. When I try to deploy my app through Google Cloud App Engine it eventually times out and doesn't work. I am not really sure what is causing the error. I think I have configured everything correctly in my Google Cloud Console. I think it may have something to do with either correctly connecting to my Google SQL Database, something goes wrong with the App Factory strategy or the APScheduler is causing problems.

This is the error that I get:

```
    Finished Step #3 - "post-buildpack"
    PUSH
    DONE
    ------------------------------------------
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
    ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation [apps/recipe-scraper-inside-my-site/operations/e1dca938-    fd40-4113-a849-65cd0324c912] timed out. This operation may still be underway.
```

My Application Directory is:

- Website

  - **init**.py
  - templates
  - .env
  - *other python files for project*
- main.py
- app.yaml
- requirements.txt

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
    runtime: python
    env: flex
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
    
    runtime_config:
      operating_system: ubuntu22
    
    manual_scaling:
      instances: 1
    resources:
      cpu: 1
      memory_gb: 0.5
      disk_size_gb: 10
    
    # Here is where you set your environment variables
    env_variables:
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: 'mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@/<database name>?    unix_socket=/cloudsql/<connection ID>'
    
     app_config_secret_key: '<secret key>'
```

I am also using the app factory strategy to create my app.

Here is my main.py file:

```
    from website import create_app
        
    app = create_app()
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my **init**.py file:

```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from os import path
    from flask_login import LoginManager
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
    from .tasks import get_gratitude_opted_in_users_and_send_to_all
    from os import getenv
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    # create SQLAlchemy object
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    # set database name
    DB_NAME = "database.db"
     
    # define function to create database
    def create_database(app):
        # if database file does not exist
        if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
            # create all database tables with Flask app instance
            db.create_all(app=app)
            # print message to indicate database creation
            print('Created Database!')
    
    # define function to create Flask application
    def create_app():
        # create Flask app instance with current module name
        app = Flask(__name__)
    
        load_dotenv()
        # set secret key for app
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = getenv('app_config_secret_key')
        # set URI for database
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    
        # initialize SQLAlchemy object with Flask app instance
        db.init_app(app)
    
        scheduler = APScheduler()
    
        scheduler.api_enabled = True
        scheduler.init_app(app)
    
        @scheduler.task('cron',id='do_job_1', hour=17, misfire_grace_time=900)
        def job1():
            with scheduler.app.app_context():
                user_data = User.query.with_entities(User.phone_number).filter_by(gratitude_text_opt_in_status=True).all()
                gratitude_opted_in_user_list = user_data
            print(user_data)
            get_gratitude_opted_in_users_and_send_to_all(gratitude_opted_in_user_list)
    
        scheduler.start()
    
        # import 'views' blueprint module
        from .views import views
        # import 'auth' blueprint module
        from .auth import auth
    
        # register 'views' blueprint with app instance
        app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
        # register 'auth' blueprint with app instance
        app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    
        # import User and Note models
        from .models import User, Note
    
        # create all database tables
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
    
        # create LoginManager object
        login_manager = LoginManager()
        # set login view for app
        login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
        # initialize LoginManager object with Flask app instance
        login_manager.init_app(app)
    
        # define function to load user from User model by ID
        @login_manager.user_loader
        def load_user(id):
            return User.query.get(int(id))
    
        return app
```

I was hoping for the app to successfully build and connect to my database but each time it tries to build it is unsuccessful and fails. I have tried to look through the console logs, but I am too new to coding to really know how to read it and what part is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to check the App Engine service logs to get a better understanding of why the app deployment is timing out.

In terms of your app itself. Using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#flask-sqlalchemy) with Flask-SQLAlchemy would be the recommended approach to connect to your instance from your Python app.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes


# Python Connector database connection function
def getconn():
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            "project:region:instance-name", # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
            "pymysql",
            user="my-user",
            password="my-password",
            db="my-database",
            ip_type= IPTypes.PUBLIC  # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
        )
        return conn

app = Flask(__name__)

# configure Flask-SQLAlchemy to use Python Connector
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    "creator": getconn
}

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Feel free to update your question if the logs provide more details.